# Why I am getting undefined on using document.write()?

Tags: javascript, oop

Why I am getting undefined in browser while using document.write() ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Person (name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.greeting = function() {
            document.write("Hello " + name +  " Go rock the industry!!");
        };
    }

    var person1 = new Person("Sara");
    var person2 = new Person("Bob");

    document.write(person1.name + "<br>");
    document.write(person1.greeting() + "<br>");
    document.write(person2.name + "<br>");
    document.write(person2.greeting() + "<br>");

</script>
```

In browser I get this output:

```
Sara
Hello Sara Go rock the industry!!undefined
Bob
Hello Bob Go rock the industry!!undefined
```

Comment: `document.write` returns `undefined`. You're using `document.write` inside `document.write`. Instead, just return the string from function `return 'Hello ' + name ...`.

Comment: It'd be better if you define the `greetings` method on `Person` prototype and refer to name as `this.name` and not use `document.write` to add content on body.

Comment: @Tushar you mean like this                                                                       `function Person (name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.greeting = function() {
   document.write("Hello " + this.name +  " Go rock the industry!!");
  };
 }

 var person1 = new Person("Sara");    
 document.write(person1.name + "<br>");
 person1.greeting(); `

Comment: @rockstone Please see my answer

Comment: @Tushar Ok got it works fine :) :)

Comment: Like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/kkorn1wL/)

Comment: Since you're new here please read [How does accepting an answer work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use `document.write` on a function that does not return a value, rather performs `document.write` itself. `Person.greeting()` should return a value so you can use it when calling `document.write(person2.greeting())`.

It should be something like this:

```
function Person (name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.greeting = function() {
        return ("Hello " + name +  " Go rock the industry!!");
          ▲
    };
}
```

Comment: sorry but less reputation after crossing 15+ I will do it definitely.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the `greeting` function to return a string instead of calling `document.write()` itself.

Currently, the `greeting` function is calling `document.write()` and *then* implicitly returning the value `undefined`.

When you evaluate the expression

`personX.greeting() + "<br/>"`

it evaluates to

`undefined + "<br/>"`

and, according to the rules of JavaScript string concatenation, `undefined` is first cast to the string `"undefined"` and then concatenated with the next value.

---

Edit:

If you're interested in exploring [property getter functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get), you could also refactor as

```
function Person (name) {
    this.name = name;
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'greeting', {
        get: function() {
            return "Hello " + this.name +  " Go rock the industry!!";
        }
    });
}

var person1 = new Person("Sara");
var person2 = new Person("Bob");

document.write(person1.name + "<br>");
document.write(person1.greeting + "<br>");
document.write(person2.name + "<br>");
document.write(person2.greeting + "<br>");
```

Notice how we can then access the computed value `personX.greeting` as if it were just a string property.

Depending on your environment, etc., if you can use ES2015+ syntax, you could achieve the same result with

```
class Person {

  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  get greeting() {
    return `Hello ${this.name} Go rock the industry!!`
  }
}

let person1 = new Person('Sara');
let person2 = new Person('Bob');

document.write(person1.name + "<br>");
document.write(person1.greeting + "<br>");
document.write(person2.name + "<br>");
document.write(person2.greeting + "<br>");
```

Comment: Can I do like this: `function Person (name) {`
  `this.name = name;`
  `this.greeting = function() {`
   `document.write("Hello " + this.name +  " Go rock the industry!!");`
  `};`
 `}`
 `var person1 = new Person("Sara");`
 `document.write(person1.name + "<br>");`
 `person1.greeting();`

Comment: That would also work, yes. However, it creates an odd inconsistency in how your object works; if you did it that way maybe rename the `greeting` method to `writeGreeting` or something, just so you (and any other developers) know that it's writing to the document instead of returning a string.